# <it> is inside the <title> so we can not use "value-of"

Tags: xslt

```
   <section>
    <title>WHO applauds the efforts of test developers to <it>innovate and respond</it> to the needs of the population</title>

<xsl:template match="section/title">
    <xsl:element name="head1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="upper-case(node())"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It is not working, please suggest

Comment: You will need to show us a representative XML input sample as well as the XML result you want to create for that sample together with an exact error description instead of saying "It is not working". `upper-case` is a function supported as part of XPath 2.0 and later by any XSLT 2 or later processor but applying it on nodes makes mostly sense in `xsl:template match="text()"`.

Comment: Input: <section>
<title>WHO applauds the efforts of test developers to <it>innovate and respond</it> to the needs of the population</title>; Output: <section>
<title>WHO APPLAUDS THE EFFORTS OF TEST DEVELOPERS TO <it>INNOVATE AND RESPOND</it> TO THE NEEDS OF THE POPULATION</title>

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="section/title//text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

together with the identity transformation (e.g. declared by `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` in XSLT 3 or spelled out as

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

in earlier versions).

You can then override it for any other transformations you want or need by adding specific templates e.g. `<xsl:template match="section/title"><head1><xsl:apply-templates/></head1></xsl:template>`.

Comment: But, I need the text in upper case

Comment: Well, the code I suggested *does* transform any text node descendants inside the `title` element to upper case letters, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknsU. Note that `upper-case` requires an XSLT 2 or later processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime or Altova.